# mysql installer забыл пароль

Tags: mysql

В общем, как-то давно устанавливал mysql, вписал пароль, и благополучно его забыл, сейчас срочно требуется заново установить его. При попытке установить просят ввести пароль который я не знаю, что можно сделать в таком случае? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [дубликаты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmysql%5D+%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C)

Answer (score 1):

Свечку не держал, но интернеты говорят вот такой рецепт для MySQL Server 5.7

Остановить MySQL, как-то так:

перейдите в папку с mysqladmin.exe:

```
cd C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin
```

Остановите MySQL сервер:

```
mysqladmin –uroot –pqwerty shutdown
```

Запустить сервер MySQL с отключенными таблицами безопасности.

Для этого запустите команду:
mysqld_safe –skip-grant-tables

Или добавьте опцию skip-grant-tables в конфигурационный файл запуска my.ini после строчки [mysqld], после чего запустите сервер.

Зайдите в MySQL как root пользователь без пароля.

После отмены запроса пароля, теперь есть такая возможность.

```
mysql –uroot
```

Установите новый MySQL Root пароль

```
mysql> UPDATE user SET Password=PASSWORD (‘НОВЫЙ ПАРОЛЬ’) WHERE User=’root’;
mysql> flush privileges
mysql> exit
```

Остановите сервер MySQL и уберите из конфигурационного файла опцию –skip-grant-tables.

```
mysqladmin –uroot –pqwerty shutdown
```

Перезагрузите MySQL сервер.

```
mysqld restart
```

Залогиньтесь в MySQL root аккаунте с использованием нового пароля.

```
mysql –uroot –pНОВЫЙПАРОЛЬ
```

"Мопед не мой", нашел тут - https://hetmanrecovery.com/ru/recovery_news/how-to-restore-mysql-root-password.htm